# TBB build with android OpenCV sample

Tags: android, opencv, build, tbb

I am doing android "face-detection" application using OpenCV. For this I have downloaded the OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk and used the "face-detection" sample. The application is working good but the video streaming is too slow. So I want to speed up the application using TBB build.

I found that **"Enabled multi-threading support with TBB"** from

http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/Android_Release_Notes#240

and also **"The good news is that Intel TBB had been build for Android and tested with some OpenCV samples"** from the following link.

http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/Android_Release_Notes#231-beta1

But I don't know how to build the TBB with "face-detection" sample. Can someone give me the steps to build TBB with the android OpenCV sample?

---

***Updated:***

***Finally I found that "OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk" basically comes with TBB.***

***(i.e)libtbb.a available in "\OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk\sdk\native\3rdparty\libs\armeabi-v7a" folder***

**and tbb-("OPENCV_3RDPARTY_COMPONENTS:=tbb libjpeg libpng libtiff libjasper IlmImf") is included in  "\OpenCV-2.4.5-android-sdk\sdk\native\jni\OpenCV.mk" file**

***But I don't know exactly this is correct. Please can anybody tell me is this correct or not?***

---

Comment: Correct. Default distribution comes with TBB enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Whether we need to enable "WITH_TBB = YES" and do I need to build again?

Comment: No and no. Setting `WITH_TBB` is usable only if you build OpenCV itself. But you don't really need to rebuild so no extra actions required. You can call `cv::getNumThreads()` to get number of working threads on **multicore** device. A number greater than 1 means that TBB is enabled and sees your cores.